# Two questions about the class of matrix rings

Tags: model-theory

Let $(R,+,-,*,0,1)$ be an associative ring with unit $1\neq0$. Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than or equal to 2. I define a matrix ring to be a ring isomorphic to the ring of all $n$ by $n$ matrices under matrix addition, additive inverse, multiplication, additive identity, and multiplicative identity for some ring $R$ and for some positive integer $n$. Let $C$ be the class of all matrix rings. Is $C$ a first-order axiomatizable class? The second question is, whether or not $C$ is first order axiomatizable, what is an explicit axiomatization of $Th(C)$, the first-order theory of $C$.

Comment: Yes, since $C$ is just the class of all associative rings with unit $1\neq 0$: every such ring is the ring of $1\times 1$ matrices over itself!

Comment: What if we consider $n$ to be greater than or equal to $2$? I have edited the question.

Comment: I figured that's what you meant! Now it's less trivial.

Comment: Some easy observations: Since $R$ embeds in any matrix ring over $R$ as the diagonal elements, the universal theory of matrix rings is just the theory of associative rings with unit $1\neq 0$. But the full theory is not universal: For example, it contains the existential axioms $\exists x\exists y (xy \neq yx)$ and $\exists x (x^2 = 0)$. I expect the general question will be quite hard, and I wouldn't be surprised if it's not an elementary class.